# FLUTTER+SQL: display Data from Database in ListViewBuilder

Tags: flutter, listview, android-listview

Im using MS SQL and I want to read data and display it in a ListViewBuilder, but Im having some difficulties.

> I dont know how to find **itemCount** (biggest problem)

> I dont know how to display **Data in ListTile**

query - "SELECT * FROM TabelTest"

Below I will show a part of code and how I want to be shown in app:

```js
// This is to get and display in terminal data from db
    Future<void> read(String query) async {
        var res = await SqlConn.readData(query);
        debugPrint(res.toString());
      }
```

Data that I need to put in ListTile
[image: data shown in terminal]

This is how I want to show data (Red underlines are main problem)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
FutureBuilder<List?>(
        future: read("SELECT * FROM TabelTest"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('Loading....');
            default:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              else
                List data = snapshot.data ?? [];
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Text((data[index] as Map)['name']);
                    });
          }
        })
```

also change this:

```
Future<List?> read(String query) async {
     final result = await SqlConn.readData(query);
     return jsonDecode(result) as List;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I got an error on line: **future: read(query)** - Undefined name 'query'

Comment: query is a String that you should add your self in order to get data from db

Comment: Im sorry that I beg, but can you help me with this problem (my knowledge is low here), also 'length' parameter is only working with Async.

Comment: how did you print that blue screen shot which contain a list?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/sql_conn/versions/0.0.3 - I used this package to connect to db
if im not wrong "debugPrint(res.toString());" - is printing the data in terminal

Comment: Ive changed a little bit the code from example (first time working with db data)

Comment: and how did you get res? by calling await SqlConn.readData(query);? if yes what did you set as query in it?

Comment: res is like storing data I get from Query, but I havent done anything with It, If im not wrong its comming with the package, because I havent used Query on my own.

Comment: as you can see in the package example, Query is something like this "SELECT * FROM IP_List", but not this one.

Comment: if you tell me what Query you use when creating database, I could help you

Comment: Can I send you somehow the Code i have, its not that big? @mail or smth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247672/discussion-between-eamirho3ein-and-dima-c).

Comment: Hi again, If have 2 questions (on same topic)  and maybe if you have 5 minutes and can answer them It would be nice

Answer (score 0):

First at all, I would recommend you to map the data into a model, its considered a good practice and avoid possible type casting related bugs.

Second, you could use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to make the asynchronous call to the SQL database. I also would modify your `read` method to return to retrieved data of the database and work together with FutureBuilder.